# Difference between <out Any?> and <*> in generics in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, variance, any

I don't understand the difference between `<out Any?>` and `<*>` in generics. I know that using `<*>` is like doing `<out Any?>` and `<in Nothing>` at the same time, but using `<out Any?>` cause the same result.

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections, it should answer your question.

Comment: If the type is bounded, `<*>` is like `<out WhateverTheBoundIs>`. Otherwise, these are effectively the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that you can't use an `out Any?` projection on a type parameter that is declared as contravariant (with `in` at the declaration site) – all of its use sites must be explicitly or implicitly `in`-projected, too.

Also, for a type parameter with an upper bound `T : TUpper`, you can't use an `out`-projection with a type argument that is not a subtype of `TUpper`. For example, if a type is declared as `Foo<T : Number>`, a projection `Foo<out Any?>` is invalid. The `out` part of the star-projection in the case of `Foo<*>` means the upper bound, not `Any?`.

Answer (score 4):

### Without Bounds

| For the generic type | `*` projection is same as |
| --- | --- |
| `Invariant<T>` | `Invariant<out Any?>` and `Invariant<in Nothing>` |
| `Covariant<out T>` | `Covariant<out Any?>` |
| `Contravariant<in T>` | `Contravariant<in Nothing>` |

### With Bounds

| For the generic type | `*` projection is same as |
| --- | --- |
| `Invariant<T : SomeType>` | `Invariant<out SomeType>` and `Invariant<in Nothing>` |
| `Covariant<out T : SomeType>` | `Covariant<out SomeType>` |
| `Contravariant<in SomeType : T>` | Lower bound is not supported |

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, I have updated the answer as per the documentation linked by you. Also great that you posted your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to memorize the behaviour of star-projection is to memorize this table:

| With `T` at declared as | Star-projection on `T` is equivalent to |
| --- | --- |
| <T: R> | <out R> |
| <out T: R> | <out R> |
| <in T> | <in Nothing> |

Since the implicit/default upper bound is `Any?` (i.e. `<T>` is equivalent to `<T: Any?>`), there is no need to separate this table into two.

---

The behaviour of star-projection is well described in [documentations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#star-projections), but is a bit verbose:

> Kotlin provides so-called star-projection syntax for this:
>
> - For `Foo<out T : TUpper>`, where `T` is a covariant type parameter with
>   the upper bound `TUpper`, `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<out TUpper>`. This
>   means that when the `T` is unknown you can safely read values of `TUpper`
>   from `Foo<*>`.
> - For `Foo<in T>`, where `T` is a contravariant type parameter, `Foo<*>` is
>   equivalent to `Foo<in Nothing>`. This means there is nothing you can
>   write to `Foo<*>` in a safe way when `T` is unknown.
> - For `Foo<T : TUpper>`, where `T` is an invariant type parameter with the
>   upper bound `TUpper`, `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<out TUpper>` for
>   reading values and to `Foo<in Nothing>` for writing values.

This particular line of description is redundant:

> `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<out TUpper>` for reading values and to `Foo<in Nothing>` for writing values.

Can be simplified as:

> `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<out TUpper>`

This is because `Foo<out TUpper>` in practice behaves exactly like `Foo<in Nothing>` for writing values -- we can't write to it. To demonstrate:

```
class Box<T: Number>(var item: T) {
    fun get(): T = item
    fun set(t: T) { this.item = t }
}
fun boxHandler1(box: Box<*>){
    //reading is possible, resolved to the upperbound at declaration site
    val number: Number = box.get()
    //writing is not possible, type of `t` of `set` is `Nothing`
    /*box.set(TODO("Impossible"))*/
}
fun boxHandler2(box: Box<out Number>){
    //reading is possible, resolved to the upperbound at declaration site
    val number: Number = box.get()
    //writing is (obviously) not possible, because covariant projection is applied
    /*box.set(TODO("Impossible"))*/
}
fun boxHandler3(box: Box<in Nothing>){
    //reading is possible, but resolved to `Any?` due to the use of `in Nothing`
    val any: Any? = box.get()
    //writing is not possible, `T` is resolved to `Nothing` when using `in Nothing`
    /*box.set(TODO("Impossible"))*/
}
```